# Top users for tag synonyms

Tags: bug, top-users

I have just today found the cool feature of top users in Stack Overflow. Finally, I would be able to be in top something in some barren tag... However, it turns out that I faced a bug:

I checked the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-activity/topusers) of [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity). I had a hope there... However it turns out that [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity) is a synonym of [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity). That is fine - I am led to the page of the top users of the [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity) tag. However, the upvotes gathered on the synonym are not counted in this report - my result should have been about 80, but is just 1 (the count I have for [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity)).

Maybe this is not a high-priority bug, but still I am filing a report here.

How to reproduce:

- Select a tag synonym
- Go to the "Top Users" page for the synonym

The report does not include the upvotes on the synonym, but it should.

Comment: Upvotes for the synonym *count for the target tag*; posts with the synonym will have been retagged. That one hit you have for `[activity]` looks like a bug to me; there is only [*one* question still matching the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1108032+[activity]), and that question has already been correctly tagged with the synonym.

Comment: So the bug is not that there is no top-users report for synonymed tags, but that you have a score for `activity` *at all*.

Comment: The synonym was created in March, but I just merged the two tags. Let's wait for a cache refresh and see if that fixes this problem.